# In a tidy dataframe, copy values over from one observation to another

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe that contains information for various countries, days and variables. I have observations for one of those variables only. A simple working example would look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(country=c("NL","NL","NL","NL","BE","BE","BE","BE"),
                 day=c("Monday","Monday","Tuesday","Tuesday","Monday","Monday","Tuesday","Tuesday"),
                 variable=c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B"),
                 value=c(8,NA,13,NA,12,NA,9,NA))
```

```
> df
  country     day variable value
1      NL  Monday        A     8
2      NL  Monday        B    NA
3      NL Tuesday        A    13
4      NL Tuesday        B    NA
5      BE  Monday        A    12
6      BE  Monday        B    NA
7      BE Tuesday        A     9
8      BE Tuesday        B    NA
```

I want to copy those observations over to the other variable, as long as `country` and `day` are identical. The end result would look like this:

```
> df
  country     day variable value
1      NL  Monday        A     8
2      NL  Monday        B     8
3      NL Tuesday        A    13
4      NL Tuesday        B    13
5      BE  Monday        A    12
6      BE  Monday        B    12
7      BE Tuesday        A     9
8      BE Tuesday        B     9
```

The actual dataframe is quite large and I would like to avoid having to build loops. A solution using pipes would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could just do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(country, day) %>%
  mutate(value = value[!is.na(value)])
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   country, day [4]
  country day     variable value
  <fct>   <fct>   <fct>    <dbl>
1 NL      Monday  A            8
2 NL      Monday  B            8
3 NL      Tuesday A           13
4 NL      Tuesday B           13
5 BE      Monday  A           12
6 BE      Monday  B           12
7 BE      Tuesday A            9
8 BE      Tuesday B            9
```

Another way would be via `fill`, though this is probably unnecessary (if needed, rather use `mutate(value = zoo::na.locf(value))` as last line since `fill` itself is quite slow):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(country, day) %>%
  arrange(country, day, value) %>%
  fill(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, value := na.omit(value), .(country, day)]
```

---

Or using `na.locf`

```
library(zoo)
setDT(df)[, value := na.locf0(value), .(country, day)]
```